# Android Активность в фоновом режиме

Tags: android, activity

Созрел вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы активность при нажатии кнопки "назад" или переключении на другую активность продолжала работу в фоновом режиме?
Я реализовал видеозапись в активности, но хочу, чтобы эта активность могла работать в фоне.

Comment: активность в фоне - это сервис

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подобные вещи нужно реализовывать в сервисах или в отдельных потоках. Максимальную логику которую должна содержать активность, это логика ее отрисовки (какие кнопочки появляются, какие исчезают, циферки меняются и т.п.) или передачи введенных данных в другие слои приложения.

Comment: А возможно прямо в сервисе изменять данные, например, TextView, находящегося в активности?

Comment: прямо -нет, так как сервис не знает, есть ли активность сейчас, но активность может подписаться на уведомления от сервиса. А по закрытию - отписываться.